# Не работает proxy в selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Здраствуйте, у меня есть маленький код который должен подключаться к сайту с разным прокси и user-agent но почему-то он никогда не может подключиться нормально. Появляется вопрос "А этот код вообще  работает или нет? Или же это прокси виноваты?" Вот сам код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import random 
agent = open('userAgents.txt').read()
agent = agent.split('\n')
r = random.randint(0,len(agent) - 1)
proxy = open('proxy.txt').read()
proxy = proxy.split('\n')
ran = random.randint(0,len(proxy) - 1)
print(agent[r])
print(proxy[ran])
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-agent="+agent[r]);
options.add_argument("--proxy-server="+proxy[ran]);
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.houzz.ru/professionals/searchDirectory?location=%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F&topicId=14028&p=120')
```

Буду рад любой помощи!

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "185.114.137.14:2507" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("http://2ip.ru")
```

вот код для подключения к сайту через прокси, каждый раз для подключения нового прокси(если будет массив с прокси) нужно будет закрывать браузер **driver.quit()** потом открывать опять